# EmptyResultDataAccessException: No entity found for query on JPA merge

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

I am writing a web application using spring 3 and hibernate 3.5 with JPA.

I am using the following code:

```
Buy buy = buyDAO.find(buyId);
buy.setNum(getNum());
buyDAO.merge(buy);
```

The `find` returns an entity (i see it in debug) but the `buyDAO.merge` throws the exception stated above.

I know that this exception is thrown only if i use `query.getSingleResult()` and there is no row in the DB for my query.

I am truly baffled by this, I tried every trick I know. I moved these lines to a different method, i tried using a transaction buy nothing works.

Comment: Not sure I understand. JPA's getSingleResult() throws an exception if nothing is found, and Hibernate's uniqueResult() returns null. So the above code would systematically throw and exception.

Comment: @JB Nizet, sorry, i forgot to mention i implemented the default find to return null in case there is no entity found. The above find does return an entity and it is the merge that throws the exception

Comment: @JMelnik, why should I flush aster using a setter?

Comment: It is [Spring's exception](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/dao/EmptyResultDataAccessException.html), at least go for a spring.